# Load published nodes of certain content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I have to load nodes of certain content type that are published.

Any built in function already available for this purpose?

Comment: What do you mean, load?  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @PatrickKenny, Yes, like node_load() and node_load_multiple() but have conditions on content type and published status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a bunch of nodes based on custom parameters, you have to use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7). It replaces the `$conditions` array `noad_load_multiple` used.

Comment: Thanks. I was not yet experienced EntityFieldQuery, now I read about it found it as useful for this purpose. After querying I have to load node with `$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));` As shown here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3/whats-the-proper-use-of-entityfieldquery