# how it's possible to load nodes by taxonomy terms

Tags: nodes

Here im loading nodes by "type" article, i want to call nodes by another id , but this id is in another table, should i join tables , or it is some other way to do this

```
$type = "article";

          $build = array();
          if ($nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type))); {
              $build['nodes'] = node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser');
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 conditions are deprecated, it is preferable to use EntityFieldQuery to retrieve a list of entity IDs. You can see more here: 
[About EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x)

In this answer you can see an example: [What's the proper use of EntityFieldQuery?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3/whats-the-proper-use-of-entityfieldquery)

In Drupal 8 you can do something like that:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('your_taxonomy_field', 'your taxonomy id')
->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have figure it out, thank you, here is it

function category1_page() {

```
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

      $query
          ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
          ->fieldCondition('field_blog_category', 'tid', 4);





      $result = $query->execute();

      $build = array();
      if ($nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']))); {
          $build['nodes'] = node_view_multiple($nodes, 'full');
      }


    return $build;

  }
```